# Invoke ApplicationCommands.Close in separated class WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I would like to close my Window App using binding by clcking button in App.
Xaml WPF class:

```
<CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"
                        Executed="CloseCommandHandler"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Button Content="Closer" Command="ApplicationCommands.Close"/>
```

And it another class ViewModel.cs use this method.

```
    private void CloseCommandHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

code behind:

```
CommandBinding CloseCommandBinding = new 
CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, CloseCommandHandler);
```

This code works only for the one class (my wpf app .xaml.cs). I would like to separate c# and xaml code as MVVM standard by sending C# code to another class.

User methods works like this ex:

```
  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static custom:ClassXXX.CustomRoutedCommand}"
                    Executed="ExecutedCustomCommand"
                    CanExecute="CanExecuteCustomCommand" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>
```

But I cannot launch ApplicationCommands in another class
How to set path or whatever to invoke method of ApplicationCommands which will take sender nad event as arguments in my second class ViewModel.cs to use Close() 
 method ?

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following as needed in your ViewModel:

1.

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

2.

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

Or the alternative way like that :

**Xaml**

```
<...Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TheWindowToClose}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public RelayCommand<Window> CloseWindowCommand { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    this.CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand<Window>(this.CloseWindow);
}

private void CloseWindow(Window window)
{
    if (window != null)
    {
       window.Close();
    }
}
```